# Multiple Image swap when Image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a multiple image swap on images. What I would like  to achieve is,

I have 6 images on the page, if image #1 is clicked, its switches to a different image, same with image #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, If a image is clicked, all 6 images change.

When the cursor rolls over an image, it changes to the same image that this image would change to when clicked, the other images don't change at this point, only when clicked do all the images change.

Help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Below is what I have got so far, ive added all the images as a reference, jsfiddle doesn't work with this though but all the code it there. I would like it to use jquery but Im already using jquery in the same document and dont want conflict  

The image called 'none' is what all other images change to when another is clicked. 

http://jsfiddle.net/htUf7/2/

Comment: Is there anybody that could help me ?